# Extracting job description linkedin

Tags: python, web-scraping

i tried to extract job title, company, location and description.

[example of job page](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/3100873051/?eBP=JOB_SEARCH_ORGANIC&recommendedFlavor=SCHOOL_RECRUIT&refId=Wqw%2FZJoozuEMkULyEdZcSg%3D%3D&trackingId=KSBWukT8OL%2FuKUlJxw1xOA%3D%3D&trk=flagship3_search_srp_jobs)

i managed to get job title, company, location since each span has their class name.
i struggle to get job description because they don't have class for their span. part of their description also located in a list. i tried to extract text using absolute xpath it doesn't work.

```py
from io import StringIO
from parsel import Selector
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge('C:/Users/users/Downloads/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe')

#accessing linkedin
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

# login
username = driver.find_element_by_name('session_key')
username.send_keys(parameter.email)
password = driver.find_element_by_name('session_password')
password.send_keys(parameter.password)
submit = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign-in-form__submit-button')
submit.click()
sleep(2)

driver.get(parameter.siteQuery)
sleep(5)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='disabled ember-view job-card-container__link']")
links =[link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]
sleep(1)


for link in links :
    driver.get(links)
    sleep(5)
    # moreinfo =driver.find_element_by_class_name('artdeco-card__action')
    # moreinfo.click()
    sel= Selector(text=driver.page_source)
    title = sel.xpath('//h1[@class="t-24 t-bold"]/text()').extract()
    company = sel.xpath('//span[@class="jobs-unified-top-card__company-name"]/text()').extract()
    location = sel.xpath('//span[@class="jobs-unified-top-card__bullet"]/text()').extract()
    description = sel.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/article/div/div[1]/span/text()').extract()
```

i tried extracting straight form div also didn't work

```
description = sel.xpath('//*[@id="jobs-details"]/span/text()').extract()
```

i use parsel.Selector and Selenium

any idea how to get the whole description?
thanks before

Comment: Are you doing login right? Because without login i don not have this id "jobs-details". Put your whole code, so we can help you. I get job description without login and only with python request and BeautifulSoup. If you want i can post the answer.

Comment: oh, sorry i don't know that it would be different. i already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out after i realize i can just extract the whole html elements. so i just take the whole span and then clean them later

Extracting from span :

```
descriptions = sel.xpath('//*[@id="job-details"]').extract()
listDescriptions.append(descriptions[0])
```

Cleaning the data :

```
listDescriptions2=[]
for description in listDescriptions :
    description = BeautifulSoup(description,features='html.parser').text
    description = re.sub(r'\n', '', description)
    listDescriptions2.append(description)
```